# Error FOSUserBundle / User Entity already done

Tags: symfony, authentication, admin, panel

I have this error when i try to do http://localhost:8000/profile or any search : 
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Compile Error: Access level to AppBundle\Entity\User::$id must be protected (as in class FOS\UserBundle\Model\User) or weaker

in User.php line 19

I just want to create a webpage for admin for my application (that webpage will be like a dashboard) and i don't know how to set access to this webpages for only admin so i tried with FOSUser with a login but if there is a quicker method just tell me (i tried the method : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html but that don't work to it just reload the page when i click submit.)

pls help

My config.yml :

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where 
the app is deployed
# 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#
application-related-configuration
parameters:
locale: en
image_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/uploads/images'

framework:
#esi: ~
translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
secret: '%secret%'
router:
    resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
    strict_requirements: ~
form: ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation: { enable_annotations: true }
#serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
default_locale: '%locale%'
trusted_hosts: ~
session:
    # 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html
#handler-id
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: 
'%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
fragments: ~
http_method_override: true
assets: ~
php_errors:
    log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug: '%kernel.debug%'
strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: '%database_host%'
    port: '%database_port%'
    dbname: '%database_name%'
    user: '%database_user%'
    password: '%database_password%'
    charset: UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: 
 '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #path: '%database_path%'

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }

fos_user:
registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
service:                               # this lines
    mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift # this lines
from_email:
    address: "testapp@testapp.com"
    sender_name: "Test App"
```

My security file :

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /list
            always_use_default_target_path : true

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And that is my user entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
* User
*
*  @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints=
{@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_id_uindex", columns={"id"}), 
@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_username_uindex", columns=
{"username"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_profile_id_fk", 
columns={"id_profile"}), @ORM\Index(name="user_localisation_id_fk", 
columns={"id_location"})})
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @UniqueEntity("username", groups={"Default", "Patch"})
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
const ROLE_USER = 'ROLE_USER';
const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Default", "Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Default", "Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Serializer\Type("string")
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getPassword() === this.getRetypedPassword()",
 *     message="Password does not match",
 *     groups={"Default", "Patch"}
 * )
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Default"})
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Deserialize"})
 */
private $retypedPassword;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Serializer\Groups({"Deserialize", "user_detail"})
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/",
 *     message="Password must be seven characters long and contain at least one digit code, upper case, and lower case letter!",
 *     groups={"Default", "Patch"}
 * )
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $enabled = '1';

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Localisation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Localisation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_location", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idLocation;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Profile
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_profile", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idProfile;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="idUserOne")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friend",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_one", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_two", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $idUserTwo;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="idUserInvited")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="list_invited",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_invited", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_place_invited", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $idPlaceInvited;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", mappedBy="idUserPresent")
 */
private $idPlacePresent;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Place", inversedBy="idUserPlace")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_place",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user_place", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_place_place", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $idPlacePlace;

/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array", length=200)
 * @Serializer\Exclude()
 */
private $roles;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->idUserTwo = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlaceInvited = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlacePresent = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idPlacePlace = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId(): int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId(int $id): void
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * @param string $username
 */
public function setUsername(string $username): void
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword(): string
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPassword(string $password): void
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnabled(): bool
{
    return $this->enabled;
}

/**
 * @param bool $enabled
 */
public function setEnabled(bool $enabled): void
{
    $this->enabled = $enabled;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIdLocation()
{
    return $this->idLocation;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $idLocation
 */
public function setIdLocation($idLocation): void
{
    $this->idLocation = $idLocation;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIdProfile()
{
    return $this->idProfile;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $idProfile
 */
public function setIdProfile($idProfile): void
{
    $this->idProfile = $idProfile;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdUserTwo(): \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
{
    return $this->idUserTwo;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idUserTwo
 */
public function setIdUserTwo(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idUserTwo): void
{
    $this->idUserTwo = $idUserTwo;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlaceInvited(): \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
{
    return $this->idPlaceInvited;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlaceInvited
 */
public function setIdPlaceInvited(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlaceInvited): void
{
    $this->idPlaceInvited = $idPlaceInvited;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlacePresent(): \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
{
    return $this->idPlacePresent;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePresent
 */
public function setIdPlacePresent(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePresent): void
{
    $this->idPlacePresent = $idPlacePresent;
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIdPlacePlace(): \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
{
    return $this->idPlacePlace;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePlace
 */
public function setIdPlacePlace(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $idPlacePlace): void
{
    $this->idPlacePlace = $idPlacePlace;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getRetypedPassword(): string
{
    return $this->retypedPassword;
}

/**
 * @param string $retypedPassword
 */
public function setRetypedPassword(string $retypedPassword): void
{
    $this->retypedPassword = $retypedPassword;
}

/**
 * Returns the roles granted to the user.
 *
 * <code>
 * public function getRoles()
 * {
 *     return array('ROLE_USER');
 * }
 * </code>
 *
 * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
 * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
 * is created.
 *
 * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}

/**
 * @param array $roles
 */
public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
}

/**
 * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
 *
 * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
 *
 * @return string|null The salt
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
}

/**
 * Removes sensitive data from the user.
 *
 * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
 * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
}
}
```

Comment: As it's written, have you try to replace "private $id;" by "protected $id;" ?

Comment: dont work .....

Comment: now i have this : An instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface must be injected in FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler to render templates.